# Inscription or dedication

Tags: positioning

I would like to have a white page in Latex with a small inscription in my thesis. I just want to write "To my father" on the right of the page, a bit above the middle of the page.

Any help?

Comment: Could you give a MWE (it'd be especially useful to know which class you are using)?

Answer (score 1):

You could say something like

```
\documentclass{book}          
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{a title} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%maybe more stuff
\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty} %clears head and foot
\vspace*{5cm} %adjust spacing as you like
\begin{center} % i think this should be centered
To my father
\end{center}
\vfill
%some content.. here fake
\chapter{a chapter}
\lipsum[30]

\end{document}
```

---

Thanks to Barbara Beeton in the comment for some valuable suggestions

Comment: two suggestions: `\vspace*` will not disappear at the top of the page.  and `\centering` needs to be turned off; here's a situation where the `center` environment would be preferable.  however, it's a bit unclear whether a centered or a flush-right text is wanted ("the right of the page" might actually be intended as "the right-hand page"); if flush right, that would also be best buried in an environment so it doesn't persist.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I knew there was some way around the `\par` , thanks for reminding me. Also, you are right about the centering. So I updated my answer. Until the OP states otherwise I continue to read the request as "on the right hand page"